# Summarize data in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, group-summaries

I have a table in Excel with dates and values. Every day there were a number of different values.

I want to summarize how many of each value there were every day.

Example:
From this

```
Date  Value

10/1  Blue
10/1  Blue
10/1  Red
11/1  Blue
11/1  Blue
```

I want to get a new table with something like this:

```
     10/1    11/1
Blue    2       2
Red     1       0
```

I'm convinced this is possible to do in VBA/Excel. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The closest built in feature I can think of is insert->pivot table

Comment: @TheJohlin: Yes it is possible to do it in VBA or by using FORMULAS but it might not be necessary to use VBA/FORMULAS for this :) Use a Pivot as Alex suggested.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for! Is it possible to mark a comment as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, just as Alex K said, to use the Privot Table function included in Excel.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first table is in A1 and the second in E1, you could use a formula in F2 like:

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$6=F$1)*($B$2:$B$6=$E2))
```

This is an array formula so you need to validate it by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

A2:A6 is the range with the dates, B2:B6 the range with the colors in your first table.
The first part of the formula says: Retain records where the value in column A is 10/1 ( = F1).

The second part says : Retain records where the value in column B is Blue ( = E2).

The '*' is equivalent to AND.

More about it here: [Multiple conditions in excel 2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152959/multiple-conditions-in-excel-2002)